# Is it possible to pass a php variable inside javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass a php variable inside javascript bt it is not working.

```
<a href="javascript:wait1();getPass('<?php echo $current?>');">Comment</a>
```

Is it possible to do so or I may be incorrect somewhere...

Thanks for your response in advance! :)

Comment: For me its working fine when I assign a value `<?php $current="hai" ?>`

Comment: Put a `;` after `$current` and/or put a space after `$current` : `<$php echo $current; ?>`

Comment: can you elaborate on "not working"? what is the html output?

Comment: I would consider refactoring the link to call a javascript function that wraps the wait() and getPass() calls, and put the php part in a variable assignment statement. It will be easier for you to read your code later that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dynamically generating Javascript. You will save yourself some headaches if when you need to do this you, keep it simple. Transfer the data from  PHP to Javascript in the simplest way possible at the top of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var $current = '<%? echo $current; %>';
</script>
```

As others have pointed out, you will want to encode and quote your php variable, using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (in which case you probably won't need the quotes), or a simpler escape function if you know the possible values.

Now, your inline code can be simpler:

```
<a href="javascript:wait1();getPass($current);">Comment</a>
```

A final recommendation would be to pull this out into its own function, and use the "onclick" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably should change 'java' tag to 'javascript'.

Regarding your question - PHP is parsed on the server side, while Javascript runs on the client side. If you are not going to use AJAX and asynchronous calls, you could write values to the JS source, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var foo = <?php echo $yourData; ?>;
  alert(foo);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="javascript:wait1();getPass('<?=$current?>');">Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` if your PHP has it.
This will automatically **quote and escape** your string and ensures that special characters are properly encoded to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
However, I think you will have to pass UTF-8 strings to this function.

And [vol7ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183181/vol7ron) has a good point – you should put a semicolon `;` after your statement and put a space between that and the question mark `?` for better legibility.

```
<a href="javascript:wait1();getPass(<?php echo json_encode($current); ?>);">Comment</a>
```

You can also pass booleans, ints and even entire arrays to `json_encode()` to pass them to JavaScript.

Comment: pretty sure the `?` *won't* be interpreted as an operator.

Comment: Thanks ! I couldn't observe that either with my version of PHP but was not sure. Removed that part.